# Stripe function presentPaymentSheet not working in iOS Flutter but working in android? What's the issue?

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, stripe-payments

I used flutter_stripe package for using stripe in my app but when I invoke the function presentPaymentSheet, it works perfectly fine for android but doesn't work for iOS. What could be the possible issue? I used firebase functions for the same.

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't work for iOS`? can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: when I invoke the presentPaymentSheet, the card screen appear on the screen in android. But in iOS, nothing appears and there's nothing in the logs too

Comment: would be helpful if you can share the code that causes the error you mention and the some snapshot of the screen in Android and IOS

Comment: https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/issues/115 please check on this

Comment: @TryHarder got the answer. I had GooglePay and ApplePay enabled so for some reason it was working in android but wasn't working in iOS, when I turned both of them off, it worked. Thanks for helping!